# How do I get a vanilla GNOME after Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Some people (me) would prefer the straight GNOME experience as opposed to the Unity style desktop offered in Ubuntu 17.10.

How can I get the standard GNOME desktop and interface?

Comment: @Rinzwind I was lead to believe that beta2 (the currently available) is the final beta?

Comment: @Rinzwind [final beta is already released](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/09/29/ubuntu-17-10-artful-aardvark-final-beta-released/), isn't it?

Comment: Oh darn it. It is already october :D Sorry!

Comment: @Rinzwind When you get to be my age, you need a calendar to keep track of the year!  :)

Comment: 48 overhere ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind  Ah, to be young again!  57 over here!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two methods to easily gain a more GNOME like experience in Ubuntu 17.10.

The first method is to run the program

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
```

This will undo many of the features that have been added to GNOME, such as the always-on dock, but will leave the Ubuntu color scheme.

The second method is to execute the command

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

This will install the GNOME themes as expected from prior versions of Ubuntu GNOME, change the Plymouth splash screens, and install several common GNOME utilities.

Comment: Nice! But don't we have to remove anything?

Comment: @pomsky Not that I noticed - I had previously removed `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`, but that (and quite a bit of other stuff) is removed or disabled by the `vanilla-gnome-desktop` package

Comment: I have not tried it but as far as I know the default ubuntu desktop is nothing more than a theme and an extension.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I would have thought so too, except for the 100+ additional packages installed by `vanilla-gnome-desktop`

Comment: @CharlesGreen I've upgraded from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. There was a separate *GNOME* session (+ GNOME on Xorg) offered at the login screen along with the default *Ubuntu* session (+ Ubuntu on Xorg) one gets after a fresh installation. This GNOME session is identical to my 17.04 setup, Ubuntu Dock and appindicators were disabled by default, Adwaita theme was available (removed in fresh 17.10) etc.

Comment: @pomsky That's great!  I did not do an upgrade, but a fresh install.  My own experience with the upgrades is that after three or four....

Comment: And if you want to get rid of the Ubuntu shenanigans in the DE selector use `sudo apt purge ubuntu-session`.

Comment: So what is the difference then between this and install [`gnome-session`](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/install-vanilla-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10)?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda A huge pile of dependancies `vanilla-gnome-desktop` installs quite a few utilities related to gnome.  I have not tested just using `gnome-session` yet, having messed up my system to the point of reinstallation yesterday.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Tested both - `vanilla-gnome-session` loads pretty much the entire Ubuntu-gnome experience, from the initial plymouth screen onwards.  `gnome-session` undoes some (most?) of the  Unity-like features of 17.10 and replaces with Gnome behaviour, but keeps the Unity-like themes.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Maybe it would be good then and important for your answer to contain that distinction given that both packages do exist and various guides point to either one of them.

Comment: @CharlesGreen `gnome-session` installs none of the usual tools like libreoffice and some of the extensions and a lot of the X stack. tested it as i went bare metal. All in all 171 packages less are installed by `gnome-session`, worth about 400 MB.

Comment: @Videonauth I think you are correct - as a dependency, `vanilla-gnome-desktop` includes `gnome-session`, but the other items such as libre-office are only included as recommends

Comment: @CharlesGreen how will installing "vanilla" differ from the old Ubuntu-Gnome? any missing or added programs/features.  Alternately  what features are missing/added over Ubuntu-Gnome when just installing gnome-session.  i.e. are either identical to the ubuntu-gnome or if not which is the closest

Comment: @TrailRider Although not an expert...  'vanilla-gnome' will be what you used to have from Ubuntu-Gnome.  Gnome-session is just the gnome screen layout, less of the unity like look, and none of the gnome applications that you got with Ubuntu-gnome.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thank you that was what i had gathered but wanted to clarify.  I was not sure if vanilla pulled in more other programs and dependencies than ubuntu-gnome had

Answer (score 0):

If you want **full GNOME**, you can install it by using:

```
sudo apt install gnome
```

This package installs around 293 packages/utilities and on the other hand `vanilla-gnome-desktop` package installs around 170 packages/utilities which in my opinion aren't required just to experience **Vanilla GNOME**. You can install a 'minimal' version of vanilla GNOME which need only 4 new packages using:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

It doesn't include additional packages (which many of times are useless) and GNOME plymouth but you can experience vanilla GNOME without using much space.

Comment: I'll try this on a VM - my personal preference was the Ubuntu-gnome flavor (I've only used Ubuntu since 12.04) and got to prefer that desktop.  I *think* that the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` feels more like Unity, which had originally caused me problems with one of my laptops.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I'm using ubuntu-gnome-desktop since Ubuntu 16.04. And currently I'm on 18.04 and using the same. I've experienced no particular difference as far performance and appearance are considered. I can't comment on apps since I've considered only DE. And I'll strongly suggest to stick to at least some default apps. Moreover `ubuntu-desktop` in 18.04+ is Unity like GNOME.