# Delete Unity after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, 17.10

I've just upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10. Now that I use Gnome, how can I delete Unity and all unnecessary attached packages ?

Comment: I'd be cautious of removing a package as involved as unity - the consequences of removing a desktop are not always readily apparent.  If you are looking for the vanilla gnome desktop, see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04)

Comment: As noted above, you'd be ahead to do a clean install, or else just leave the Unity cruft alone until the next time you *do* install clean.