# Default gnome on 17.10

Tags: gnome, default

I was using Ubuntu GNOME for years and I just tried new Ubuntu 17.10, and I absolutely hate it. Is there an easy way to get default GNOME?

Basically I want to:

1. Remove dock on the left
2. Add top left hot corner
3. Adwaita Theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Remove dock on the left

Run

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

#### Add top left hot corner

Run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners true
```

#### Adwaita Theme

Run

```
sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard
```

Install *GNOME Tweaks* by

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Launch Tweaks and select Adwaita in *Appearance > Themes > Applications*.

---

(Or simply follow the Q&A I [linked in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04))