# Gnome Desktop on 17.10

Tags: gnome, .desktop

Why does my 17.10 still have unity desktop. I installed 17.10 on a previously used but formatted 500 gig hard drive but it came up with unity desktop. I instaled 17.10 on another reformatted drive this week and it has tge GNOME desktop?

Comment: It *is* the gnome desktop, dressed up in a unity-like theme.  You can change specifically to unity at login time (by choosing a specific desktop), and you can change to a more Gnome-like experience if you want:  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04)

Comment: Ubuntuhas changed to gnome-shell. If  your upgraded box is still on unity it may be related to either your graphics card (nvidia) or you need to update the login manager.

Comment: After running all the commands in the terminal I still dont have a gnome desk top.  No option to use GNOME comes up in my logon screen?

Comment: Got it. I ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure GDM
It came up with a screen saying I could only run one configure so I chose GDM.  The GNOME options were there on restart.  Thanks