# Can't remove ubuntu dock after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, ubuntu-dock

I just upgrade to ubuntu to 18.04 fr0m 16.04. I was using unity launcher but when I upgrade ubuntu version it switched with dock (I assume)

Now I want to remove or hide dock. I tried [these method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979732/how-can-i-hide-the-dock-in-gnome)s but none of them worked for me..

Have you another advice ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030138/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-dock-in-ubuntu-18 but **you don't want to do that**. Use Settings > Dock and set it to hide.

Comment: Not sure if you already know this but, when you sign on you can click the gear icon next to your password and select `Unity` interface so life is the same as it was in 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

The big dock on the left. In other versions you could escape unity launcher by going to gnome Gnome tweaks are not showing it as an extension, even though it looks a lot like the dash to dock.

[Tweaks -> Extensions ->Dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huvyT.png)

you can find autohide here

Comment: In answers we should provide the actual instructions and maybe include a link as source. In this case you're merely pointing to another question/answer. Just flag it as duplicate. Please avoid link-only answers.