# Keep the Dash to Panel UI Hidden Using Shortcuts

Tags: gnome, 20.04, panel, gnome-shell-extension, extension

In some applications the Intellihide doesn't work because the app doesn't suport fullscreen (so this option does not trigger):

[image]

It's pretty uncomfortable getting interrupted by the Intellihide every time I hover the mouse near the edge of the screen.  I've tried manipulating some of the options to keep the panel hidden while I run those kind of applications without full-screen feature.

[image: Intellihide]

I came here to ask Ubuntu if there is a method to program or activate a shortcut to keep the panel hidden until I press the shortcut again? (the same way there is a shortcut to hold the panel visible)
**Hold the panel visible shortcut in the extension settings:**
[image: Shortcut hold visible]

**Edit:** No, I don't want to remove the extension. I'm just seeking for a method to keep it hidden at will. I'm going to provide an image of what I mean

**Holding the panel hidden (What I need):**
[image: keep hidden]

**Intellihide enabled (what I want to temporally disable using shortcuts)**
[image: neither of the previous]

**Edit 2:** I achieved recording the **Holding the panel hidden** by disabling temporally the extension, I haven't resolved yet the problem so I'll start a bounty.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-remove-or-disable-ubuntu-dock.html

Comment: Or this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/979732/how-can-i-hide-the-dock-in-gnome

Comment: Quite unclear what you precisely want. "Mouse a little downwards", do I understand you have the dock on the bottom in a hidden state, and you do not want it to appear on mouse hovering near the edge of the screen? What do you mean with "hold the panel down"?  Display it? Please edit your question to be a little more sharp and specific on what behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I meant keep the panel hidden even when I hover the mouse near the edge of the screen. English is not my native language so please have patience. Edit: I already edited the question with the clarifications.

Comment: "[disable / keep hidden] the Dash to Panel UI while in [full screen / kiosk mode]" would make a helpful title.

Comment: Could You try going to system settings, setting up a keyboard shortcut (I picked Alt+F11) for "Trigger fullscreen mode" (it may be named somehow different) and using that shortcut in Your application to try triggering full screen mode? I think it may work (even if there may be no typical way to trigger it in the application) and help You.

Comment: The app does not support fullscreen mode