# Auto-hide Dock in Ubuntu 20.04 as in Windows and Kubuntu

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-dock, autohide

I want to auto-hide Dock in Ubuntu 20.04, but in different way - hide Dock by default, and show it if I hover mouse on Dock side.
I think the GNOME way to hide Dock is useless...

Comment: I do not think the Gnome way is useless. 1) It is not the Gnome way to start, this is implemented by an extension and 2) some users may like it. It would be good to edit your post and delete that possibly offending part of your question. I certainly agree with you where you may prefer a dock that is hidden, but that only appears when hovering the edge of the screen. I explored hidden settings, but that does not (anymore?) appear to be possible.

Comment: It used to be possible (https://askubuntu.com/questions/979732/how-can-i-hide-the-dock-in-gnome), but I have the impression that the intellihide setting has changed (multiple options now instead of on/off, none including the desired behavior)