# How to not always show left Ubuntu Dock in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-shell, taskbar, ubuntu-dock

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 (GNOME).

Its GNOME Shell appears to have been modified to behave similar to the Unity shell, and hence on the left side panel I always see a panel (aka Ubuntu Dock) providing icons to start different apps.

[image: Screenshot of gnome shell desktop with sidebar enabled always showing on the left side]

I find it especially annoying with programs running in full screen windows.

How can I make the sidebar always disappear during normal mode?

I don't mind seeing it when in the "Activities overview" accessible by default through the super key, yet I don't want to see when I am on the desktop or in different apps.

I want to keep the title bar.

In the end, I am looking for a similar experience that was provided, if one switched to the GNOME shell on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can auto-hide the Ubuntu Dock by going to *Settings* > *Dock* and the toggling on "Auto-hide the Dock".

[image]

If you wish to have a pure GNOME experience, follow this Q&A: [How do I get a vanilla GNOME after Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04)

Answer (score 1):

This solution applies for an ubuntu gnome desktop, tested in Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04

## built-in solution:

Like stated in the post from @pomsky you can Auto-Hide the Dock in vanilla ubuntu.

`Settings->Dock->Auto-hide the Dock`

## gnome shell extension

For me, this solution is not enough. I want to have the bar fully hidden. Like in a vanilla gnome desktop. To achieve this, I am using the [Dash To Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) Gnome Shell Extension. Install it by pressing switch on the right:

[image: Dash To Dock Install]

Navigate your browser [to this site](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) to see all locally installed extensions. Note that this needs the `chrome-gnome-shell` package to be installed.

After successful installation, right click the dock and open the *Dash To Dock* Settings.

[image: Open Dash To Dock Settings]

Here you will find the Option for **Intelligent autohide**. Enable it and go to the preferences:

[image: Intelligent autohide option]

In the following settings page disable both options:

- Autohide
- Dodge windows

[image: Disable Settings here]

That's it. No annoying dash popup anymore.